# Installing Texlive

Tags: installing

Have downloaded TeX Live and stored in `~/Opstk/src/texlive/tl-20221001` with the directory being `tl-20221001`. How can I install to a local directory `~/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022` with `perl install-tl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote the [quick install page](https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html):

> To change the main installation directories (rarely needed), add
> `--texdir=/install/dir` to the `install-tl` command. To change the location of the per-user directories (where `TEXMFHOME` and others will
> be found), specify `--texuserdir=/your/dir`.

So in your case you would do `perl ./install-tl --texdir=~/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022 --no-interaction`.

You an also run the installed in interactive mode (without the `--no-interaction`) which provides a menu option that lets you customize the installation directories.

Comment: My problem is that I am getting `write(/usr/local/texlive/2022/tlpkg/texlive.tlpdb) failed: No space left on device at tlpkg/TeXLive/TLUtils.pm line 1467.`

Comment: @konmi that means your disk is full, we can't do much about that (but it will not write to `/usr/local` if you speciify a different install directory as suggested)

Comment: It shouldn't be writing to that folder at all if the files are where you say they are and you passed those parameters, so that doesn't make any sense to me. Do you have any configuration files left over from a previous install? Are `/usr/local` and `~/Opstk/bld` mounted on the same device?

Comment: Have uninstalling the existing Texlive and removed some packages.  And running installation of Tex Live.  Things are progressing but have to wait a while.

Comment: Have now installed Texlive in `~/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022`.  What do I have to do now?

Comment: I added `~/Opstk/bld/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux` to `PATH`.

Comment: Anything else to do?

Comment: Probably not, or not much. You might need to configure your editor to use the right binaries, but you might not even need to do that if your PATH is set. If you have custom packages or other resources not on CTAN you might need to put them in the proper new location as well.